# EF Core One To Many Include

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I work on a ASP.NET Core MVC Website with EF-CORE, in my database.

I have a `Doc` table and a `Signature` tables:

- one `Doc` can have many `Signatures`
- one `Signature` can have only on `Doc`.

Here's my Code First Entity Model:

#### Doc

```cs
public class Doc
{
    [Key]
    public int DocID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DocTypeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DocTypeID")]
    public virtual DocType DocType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Byte[] Data { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocID")]
    public List<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }
}
```

#### Signature

```cs
public class Signature
{
    //FK ITPolicyVersion
    [Key]
    public int DocID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DocID")]
    public virtual Doc Doc { get; set; }

    //FK EmployeeID
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Signature Date")]
    public DateTime? SignatureDate { get; set; }

    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

But when I use this request :

```cs
_applicationDBContext.Doc
    .Include(d => d.DocType)
    .Include(d => d.Signatures)
    .OrderBy(d => d.DocType)
    .ToList();
```

`d.Signatures` is always null, and I cannot figure why.

Here's what I'm trying to do in SQL :

```sql
SELECT * FROM Doc d
JOIN DocType dt ON dt.DocTypeID = d.DocTypeID
JOIN Signature s ON s.DocID = d.DocID
JOIN Employee e ON e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
```

And this work well in SQL but not with LINQ

**EDIT**

This work :

```cs
List<Doc> docs = _applicationDBContext.Doc
    .Include(d => d.Signatures)
    .ThenInclude(s => s.Employee)
    .Include(d => d.DocType)
    .ToList();
```

But not this :

```cs
List<Doc> docs = _applicationDBContext.Doc
    .Include(d => d.Signatures)
    .ThenInclude(s => s.Employee)
    .Include(d => d.DocType)
    .OrderBy(d => d.DocType)
    .ToList();
```

`Signature` became empty

How can I order this list by `DocType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was in fact an error on the orderby but it wasn't throw : DocType is an other table and doesn't implement IComparable so I just change the request like that :

```
List<Doc> docs = _applicationDBContext.Doc
                                .Include(d => d.Signatures)
                                    .ThenInclude(s=>s.Employee)
                                .Include(d => d.DocType)
                                .OrderBy(d => d.DocType.Name)
                                .ToList();
```

And it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your OnModelCreating of DbContext, have u put a relation of Doc and Signature? something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Signature>().HasOne(m => m.Doc).WithMany(m => m.Signature).HasForeignKey(m => m.DocID);
```

Comment: I've added this : `builder.Entity<Signature>().HasOne(m => m.Doc).WithMany(m => m.Signatures).HasForeignKey(m => m.DocID);` but it's not seem to be better, please see the edit, my initial request is maybe not what I'm need

Comment: @Alexis Does this solve your original issue of `d.Signatures` being `null` (although it should not happen even w/o fluent configuration)? The edit turns your original question into a totally different question, so you should remove the edit and post a separate question. But before that you should resolve the current question.

Comment: @IvanStoev I will make another question for this thanks. Your solution doesn't solve the problem for signatures, it's still null.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ef core page on relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

You should be able to simplify to something like this.

Keep in mind lots of things work by convention so naming is important (eg using Id for the entity key is picked up automatically by entity framework)

Where you have backwards navigation properties on 'child' objects you need the foreign key attribute and id property OR to use the Fluent API.

```
public class Doc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DocType DocType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public List<Signature> Signatures { get; set; }
}

public class Signature {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    //backwards navigation
    public int DocForeignKey {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("DocForeignKey")]
    public Doc Doc { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Signature Date")]
    public DateTime? SignatureDate { get; set; }

    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know for the automatic Id with EF but I think it's more clear with something like "tableNameID" and add a [KEY] attribute is not that painfull, i've backward navigation on Doc for Signature.